How can i document Laravel Purity style parameters
Laravel Purity uses GET /api/posts?filters[field][operator]=value style parameters.
Anyone know how to document this?
I've tried the following:
                "parameters": [
                    {   
                        "description": "Filter data using the following syntax: filters[field][operator]=value",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },  
                        "style": "deepObject",
                        "allowReserved": true,
                        "examples": {
                            "name-contains": {
                                "value": "[name][$contains]=test",
                                "summary": "Search for forms where name contains string 'test'"
                            },  
                            "date-gt": {
                                "value": "[created_at][$gt]=2024-01-01",
                                "summary": "Search for forms created after '2024-01-01'"
                            }   
                        },  
                        "name": "filters",
                        "in": "query"
                    }
                ], 

But that creates GET /api/posts?filters=[field][operator]=value with the extra equals sign.
Is there a way to document these without having to put in every possible [field] and [operator] combination as a named parameter?

Deep nesting like obj[foo][bar]=value is not supported as of OpenAPI 3.1. Only single-level nesting obj[foo]=value is supported so far.
